# When is $an+b$ a square?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Pick two integers $a$ and $b$, and construct the arithmetic progression $an+b$. My question is, when does this contain infinitely many squares? And which terms in that sequence are the squares (i.e., for which $n$)?

For instance:

- $2n+3$ is a square infinitely often (by setting [$n=2m^2+2m-1$](https://oeis.org/A142463) for $m\in\bf Z$),
- Similarly $5n+1$ is a square when [$n=0,3,7,16,\dots$](https://oeis.org/A036666). This time the formula for which $n$ to take is not as simple, it's $n=\frac{1}{8} \left(10 m^2+2
     \left((-1)^m-5\right)
     m+(-1)^{m+1}+1\right)$.
- $9n+4$ is a square whenever [$n=9m^2+4m$](https://oeis.org/A185039), but
- $9n+5$ is never a square
- $8n+1$ is a square when $n$ is triangular

Can someone point me to a general study of this diophantine problem, $k^2=an+b$?

Comment: $k^2 = an +b$ has infinitely many solutions if $b$ is a [quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) modulo $a$.

Comment: *if and only if!

Answer (score 4):

In general, saying that there are infinitely many $an + b$ being square is the same as saying that $b$ is a quadratic residue mod $a$. Because if $b$ is a quadratic residue mod $a$, there exists $c$ such that $c^2 \equiv b \pmod{a}$. Note that all numbers in the form of $c + ka$ have their squares in the form of $an + b$.

To determine if a number $b$ is a quadratic residue mod $a$, there are ways to calculate that ([Jacobi symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol#Calculating_the_Jacobi_symbol) with the help of [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity)).

Comment: It is essential to justify your claim in the first sentence, i.e. either prove it or link to a proof.